# Flutter: code analysis and layout explorer in code at build time

Tags: flutter, dart, code-analysis, dart-analyzer, dart-build

I'm new to flutter, so I hope my question will not be too much out of scope:

I would like to **extract meta informations about the app at build time**. The idea is to have JSON tree of the app widgets and send it to an external database via API call for further statistics

Here is a simplified example of my app structure

```sh
Scaffold
├─ Page1: homePage
│ ├── BtnWidget: btn1
│ └── RandomWidget
└─ Page2: profilePage
  └── BtnWidget: btn2
```

And ideally I would like to be able to retrieve something like:

```json
{
  "homePage": { // identifier is used when found to uniquely describe a widget
    "type": "screen",
    "children": ["btn1"], // hierarchical information
    "parent": null,
  },
  ...
}
```

**Is it possible to access the widget list and their properties in code at build time ? Or anytime ?**

---

**My researchs:**

I have looked this package: [build](https://pub.dev/packages/build/) that seems a good lead but I didn't fully understood how it worked for my purpose
I have also searched on google or stack overflow but couldn't find nothing relevant

---

**The goal:**

When I build a new application, the widget tree and some meta data (version, new features...) is send to a database where data are crossed with user app interaction data (click, swipe...) to track UX statistics along with app versions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you are looking for is close to `debugDumpApp()` or  `debugDumpRenderTree()`. Check out this doc https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/code-debugging#render-tree, I guess it's a good starting point.

Comment: Hi, nice answer, too bad it doesn't meet the `at build time` requirement...or do I miss something ?

Comment: You asked "at build time ? Or anytime ?" ^^ 
Could you maybe precise why you need it at build time? Because if the purpose is just to send the widgets tree somewhere, you could have a simple script or command that builds the app, runs in debug mode and collects the infos, then send them.

Comment: I will be glad to hear about how is that possible :) However I edited the question to clarify the goal